# Flattening uneven array - Out of bounds exception error

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation, multidimensional-array

I am trying to flatten this array:

```
int[][] arr = { {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5},
                {6},
                null,
                {},
                {7,8}};
```

I can see that in the first couple of steps it fills out the new array, but then I get the out of bounds exception error. I don't understand where my mistake is.

```
public static int[] concAr (int[][] arr) {
    int countels=0;
    for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++) {
        if (arr[r] == null|| arr[r].length==0)
            continue;
        for (int c = 0; c < arr[r].length; c++) {               
            countels++;
        }
    }
    int[] flatAr = new int[countels];
    for(int i = 0; i < countels; i ++) {
        if(arr[i]!=null) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j ++) {
                flatAr[(i * arr.length) + j] = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return flatAr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following indexing is wrong, because array lengths are different

```
flatAr[(i * arr.length) + j] = arr[i][j];
```

Use this after setting `count` to zero:

```
flatAr[count++] = arr[i][j];
```

Comment: thanks! this helps, but i also had to add a check for null or empty array after `for(int i = 0; i < countels; i ++) {` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`countels` is the length of the flattened array, in this case, 8.  However, in your second outer loop, you index through the original, unflattened array up to `countels`, even though your unflattened array only has 6 elements.  Once you get past those 6, you get the out of bounds exception.

The second time through, you still need to iterate the way you did the first time, and increment the index of the flattened array within the second set of loops.